# Enabling user to delete

Tags: c++

How would I enable the user to DELETE - deletes a person from the array based on user input, sorts the array, and prints out all of the entries in the new array. (Format: DELETE - LastName, FirstName)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct People
{
    std::string lname;
    std::string fname;
};

const int numNames = 2;

int main()
{
    char name[numNames][80];
    char last_name[numNames][80];
    char name_buff[1][80];

    cout << "INSERT name.\n";
    cout << "\nEntires should be of the format\n";
    cout << "Last_Name First_Name." << "\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < numNames; ++i)//use a loop to get user input
        cin >> (name[i]);

    cout << "\n";
    cout << "***Initialize check***" << "\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < numNames; ++i)//this loop will show the the user the data that has been input
        cout << (name[i]) << "\n";

    cout << "\n***Check Complete***" << "\n\n";
    cout << "Press ENTER to contine";
    cin.get();

    // This is the bubble sort.
    for (int a = 1; a <= numNames; a++)
    {
        for (int b = numNames - 1; b >= a; b--)
        {
            if (name[b - 1][0] > name[b][0])
            { // if out of order error message
                cout << "Please try again!";
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: I hope your book isn't suggesting `char[80]`. We've been using `std::string` for literally decades.

Comment: 1. Formatting is your new best friend
2. don't delete from an array, try doing it from a std::vector instead

Comment: Better use a `struct` and a `std::vector` of it instead of several separate raw arrays.

Comment: You should use an array of the struct type you defined. (And "Person" is a better name than "People" because each one represents exactly one person.)

Comment: You might want to define a few functions, rather than keeping all your code in main.

Comment: @molbdnilo or better yet, a vector.

Comment: You should also complete the input part before tackling deletion.

Comment: @jaggedSpire This is most likely the first or second "introduction to arrays" assignment, in which case using `vector` is out.

Answer (score 1):

Not so much an answer as a few hints to get you unstuck:

There is no way to actually remove an element from an array.
Instead, what you do is to keep track of how many array elements are considered "valid".
To "remove" an element, you move all the elements to the right of it one step to the left and decrement your "valid counter".
(If you're unsure how to do it, work it out on paper first.)

Some other tips:

It's much easier to handle an array of structs than a bunch of arrays.

Use the struct you defined.
I would personally rename it so its purpose is clearer (don't use plurals for singular things):

```
struct Person
{
    std::string last_name;
    std::string first_name;
};
```

Then use an array that contains such things:

```
Person people[max_persons];
```

and work with this.

Before you implement sorting and deleting, write the output bit and make sure that it works - it's going to be helpful for finding bugs in the other things.